# Kotlin with Android: Base classes and Kotlin Android Extensions

Tags: android, kotlin, findviewbyid

So i have used `Kotlin Android Extensions` and i find it very easy to use and well worth it. No more `findViewById` or `Butterknife.Bind(...)`. I have found no issue with it all all except for one situation.

In a base class, for example, `BaseActivity`, there's normally a bunch of views that will be present in all the layouts, for example, a toolbar. And common operations like `changeToolbarColor()`, or `setToolbarTitle()`.

In this simple cases, i canno't use `Kotlin Android Extensions` because, as it is a base class, the view itself will be present on multiple layouts and tho can't be property imported. In this cases i just simply use `by lazy {find<>(...)`.

Is there any way this can be accomplished with the build-in android extension plugin?

Comment: Is [Kotterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/kotterknife) an option?

Comment: was before i started to use Android Extensions :p I just simply skipped KotterKnife because it hasn't any way of re-binding views

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Kotlin Android Extensions` generates an extension function for each element on a given layout. Since extension methods exist outside the inheritance model, there is no way to define a common protocol like `abstract val toolbar:Toolbar` on the parent.

However, under the hood the extension methods only execute `findById`, if the given ID exists on a layout it will fetch the element. This means that if you maintain the same ids for your common elements inside your layouts (i.e.: all toolbars with `@id/toolbar`), you can create a dummy layout with your common elements and their respective IDs. This layout will work as a sort of interface, allowing you to do `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.base_activity_dummy.*` and thus generating the extension methods you want.

By doing the above, the `this.toolbar` on your `BaseActivity` will fetch the actual item on your concrete activity instead of the element on the dummy layout.

Of course, this technique, while convenient, is error prone and could make your program very confusing for an outsider. But again, it won't be more error prone than calling `findById` everywhere.